# Driver for Google Cloud SQL

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I'm going to use Google Cloud SQL in my application. I'm using Java programming language. I know now it's possible to use 2 drivers to connect to the database - native MySQL JDBC driver and com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver.

Could you please suggest which one is more preferable in terms of stability and performance.

Any suggestions are very appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Stan

Answer (score 1):

Currently, a Java App Engine app can connect to Google Cloud SQL using two ways:

1. com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver
2. com.google.appengine.api.rdbms.AppEngineDriver

The [first one was made public on July 15](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-cloud-sql-announce/AA6doaz3bOw) and it is the recommended way to connect. Under the hood it uses the MySQL Connector/J so it provides excellent API compatibility. The second one is older, it is a Google-specific JDBC API and it might not always behave as MySQL Connector/J.

So, use the com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver.

...